# Mouseover only active once I'm on my canvas and not my shape

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

i'm a beginner using canvas and also javascript and I'm trying to use the mouseover. I got to get it work a bit but it's only when the mouse is on the canvas, I'd like to make my square color change once my mouse is on it.

How can I get it work ?

Here's my code :

```js
  window.onload = function()
    {
        canvasEvent();
    }

    function canvasEvent()
    {
        var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.rect(150, 150, 100, 100);
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();   

        c.addEventListener("mouseover", hover, false);
        c.addEventListener("mouseout", hoverOut, false);
    }

    function hover(e)
    {
        var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
    }

    function hoverOut(e)
    {
        var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
        ctx.fill();
    }
```

```css
canvas#canvas{
    background-color:#DDDDDD;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>TEST</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="550" height="400"></canvas>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem. It works fine

Comment: You will have to read the position of the mouse each time it moves once it has entered the canvas and if it's within the bounds of the blue square draw it the square green otherwise draw it blue. (if you remember the color of the last draw you can cut down on repeatedly redrawing the canvas a bit).

Comment: @n-ata the problem here is that the color activates once my mouse enters the canvas but I don't want that. I'd like to change the color of my square once my mouse is on the square and not before. Sorry if you don't really understand what I mean

Comment: Learn about the other mouse move events - in particular mousemove itself. See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just check if mouse is on rectangle

```js
window.onload = function()
{
    canvasEvent();
}

function canvasEvent()
{
    var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.rect(150, 150, 100, 100);
    ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();   

    c.addEventListener("mousemove", e => { 

      if (
        e.offsetX >=150 && 
        e.offsetX <= 250 && 
        e.offsetY >= 150 && 
        e.offsetY<=250){
          hover();
      }
      else{
      hoverOut();
      }
    });
}

function hover(e)
{
    var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();
}

function hoverOut(e)
{
    var c=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = 'blue';
    ctx.fill();
}
```

```css
canvas#canvas{
    background-color:#DDDDDD;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>TEST</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="550" height="400"></canvas>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```